# Outgoing http requests not showing in Fiddler from java spring mvc web app

Tags: fiddler

Hi I'm sending some http requests from a java spring mvc web app and when I have fiddler open I don't see any outgoing responses.

Using this code to send to an address similar to:  http:///getstuff?stuff="whatever"

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
           log.info("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            // Create a response handler...
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

Does anybody know why these outgoing calls are not showing up in fiddler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to configure your JVM to proxy its HTTP requests? http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp

Comment: Awesome! Right from the man himself. =) Worked like a charm! Thanks.